Webpack IgnorePlugin not working with date-fns locale files
I am trying to exclude the locale files from the date-fns package in my Webpack configuration using IgnorePlugin. However, despite my configuration, Webpack is still including the locale files in the bundle. I expect the locale directory to be ignored, but it isn't working as expected.
Here is my Webpack configuration:
new webpack.IgnorePlugin({   
resourceRegExp: /[/\\]locale[/\\]/, // Ignore any file inside the 'locale' directory  
contextRegExp: /date-fns$/,         // Ensure it's within 'date-fns' 
}),

Additional Info:
I'm using esm imports for date-fns.
I'm trying to reduce the bundle size by excluding the locale files, as I only need specific locales.
Clearing the Webpack cache didn't resolve the issue.
Expected Behavior:
Webpack should ignore the locale directory, reducing the bundle size and removing the locale files from the final build.
Actual Behavior:
The locale files are still included in the bundle despite the IgnorePlugin configuration.`

To exclude all locales from the date-fns package using ContextReplacementPlugin, the configuration you've shared looks correct. Here's how it works:
ContextReplacementPlugin: This plugin is used to replace the context for dynamic imports, ensuring that Webpack skips including unnecessary locale files.
Here's a complete example based on your configuration:
import webpack from "webpack";
import path from "path";
import { supportedLocales } from "./config.js"; // assuming this config 
file exists

export default {
  resolve: {
  alias: {
  // Create an alias for date-fns-locale directory
  "date-fns-locale": path.dirname(require.resolve("date- 
  fns/package.json")),
  },
},
plugins: [
new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
  /date-fns[/\\]locale/,
  /$^/,),
  ],
};

ContextReplacementPlugin:
The first argument /date-fns[/\]locale/ tells Webpack to look for the locale directory within date-fns.
The second argument /^$/ (which matches nothing) ensures that Webpack doesn't include any files from the locale directory, effectively excluding all locales.
date-fnf refrence
